# JQuery show only when first <td> is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've pieced together some stuff to make this work, it does exactly what I want it to do, however I only want the rows below the parent to show when the #parentClick (date) is clicked and not the rest of the `<td>` in the parent row is clicked.  The idea is that all the numbers that are here will hyperlink over to another page, including the roll up ones in the parent.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wingman1487/czxhvn1r/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check to see if the original clicked element is the trigger element using

```
var originalElement = e.target;
if($(originalElement).attr('id') == 'parentClick'){
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/czxhvn1r/3/

Comment: Perfect, thanks for taking the time.  Like I said I pieced it together, but I'm still newb-ish when it comes to some of the JQuery.